# Updating AppEngine deployed version on GitHub push

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it possible to auto-deploy to AppEngine when Github receives a new commit? I found a bunch of dead documentation links that suggest it is, however I still have no idea how to set it up. There are some mentions for creating a release pipeline, but I don't see any way to do that in the cloud console anymore.

I've got my code mirroring the GitHub repository already, however I can't figure out how to link this to the deployment pipeline or even how to create a new version. Am I missing something obvious? This seems like it should be incredibly straightforward to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The entry](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2014/04/using-github-for-push-to-deploy.html) on the Google Cloud Platform blog that's supposed to explain how to achieve this is blank. It seems Google quietly killed this feature. Some people [have complained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600294/deployments-triggered-from-github-stoped-working-on-google-app-engine) that it suddenly stopped working. The only way to do this now is to use Continous Delivery/Integration tools such as [Travis CI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/google-app-engine).